# Ephemeral anonymous identities that can be slashed once forever with a single nullifier

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, anonymity

Consider a ZKP anonymous credential scheme where each tuple of `(x, identity_secret, merkle_root)` corresponds to a unique nullifier computed as `Hash(x|identity_secret)`. The prover can use this tuple repeatedly along with proving other statements.

`x` is designated on a per-session/app basis. And for a specific triple, a user can be blacklisted with the nullifier, and can not generate any new proofs without revealing the blacklisted nullifier.

Is it possible that when we blacklist one nullifier for a triple, the user as identified by `(identity_secret, merkle_root)` is permanently blacklisted ? Can the user efficiently prove to be not blacklisted ?